# Getting JSON from WCF service

Tags: jquery, wcf, json, jsonp

I have a simple WCF service application which contains a list of "room" items and a couple of methods for retrieving the information as JSON via WebInvoke. The method "GetRooms()" returns the following test items in browser:

```
    [{"RoomId":1,"RoomName":"Big Room"},
     {"RoomId":2,"RoomName":"Medium Room"},
     {"RoomId":2,"RoomName":"Small Room"}]
```

I am currently trying to retrieve the JSON in a web application using JQuery so that I can format it in a jqGrid later. I am trying to do this by using the following code:

```
<div>
<input type="button" value="Get Rooms" onclick="getRooms();">
</div>
<div id="rooms">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/jquery-1.7.1.js">
     function getRooms() {
       $.ajax({
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         type: "GET",
         url: "http://localhost:6188/RoomBookingService.svc/GetRooms",
         success: function (data) {
             var innerHtml = "";
             for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                 innerHtml += data[i].RoomId + ' ' + data[i].RoomName + '<br/>';
             }
             $("#rooms").html(innerHtml);
         }
     });
 }
</script>
</div>
```

I am getting an error which states that getRooms is not defined. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `inline` click handler use jQuery to attach the `click` handler. Try this

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/jquery-1.7.1.js">
 $(function(){
     $("input:button").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           type: "GET",
           url: "http://localhost:6188/RoomBookingService.svc/GetRooms",
           success: function (data) {
               var innerHtml = "";
               for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  innerHtml += data[i].RoomId + ' ' + data[i].RoomName + '<br/>';
               }
               $("#rooms").html(innerHtml);
           }
        });
    });
 });
</script>
<input type="button" value="Get Rooms" />
</div>
<div id="rooms"></div>
```